# Swift: CABasicAnimation returning negative value for presentation

Tags: swift

I am currently extended the class `UIView`. I have an animation function as follows:

```
     func rotate360(duration: TimeInterval) {
        let rotationAnimation = 
          CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"transform.rotation")
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotationAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(2 * CGFloat.pi)
        rotationAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
        rotationAnimation.duration = duration
       self.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
     }
```

and then I have another function to get the current temporal position within the animation:

```
    func currentRotationValue() -> Any? {
        self.layer.presentation()
        let value = self.layer.presentation()?.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation")
        return value
     }
```

For some reason when I cast the below `Any?` into a `CGFloat` i sometimes get negative numbers (As if the number is overflowing). if it is overflowing, then that means i am using a more precise datatype than `CGFloat`. I tried casting the `Any?` as a Double to see if that was enough precision but i get the same value as when it is a `CGFloat`.

Here is my code which take the view value and casts it as a CGFloat:

```
        var rotation = self.myView.currentRotationValue()
        guard let rot = rotation as? CGFloat else {
            return
        }
        var unscaledTime = rot / (CGFloat.pi * 2) * 3.0
        print("\(unscaledTime) is sometimes negative")
```

I guess it could be that i am scaling it by 3 which could overflow. my goal is to preserve exactly where i am in the rotation and then multiply that value by 3 since that is the time period of the rotation animation.

Does this mean i need to use some arbitrary precision number in order to not exceed the significand of the memory store?

**UPDATE**

actually the number is negative before i do any more arithmetic operations on it. namely immediately after casting to a CGFloat